# How to replace multiple items with same count of a different item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a custom food recipe. I'm using spawn eggs with /replaceitem because spawn eggs are not obtainable in survival. This works fine when the player crafts only one spawn egg, but when I scroll over multiple spawn eggs, I receive only 1 of the custom food. BTW this food uses custommodeldata, so I can't simply add it into the crafting recipe. I cannot seem to find a way around this. If I make the item non-stackable, such as a piece of armor, mass crafting would be impossible. If I make an item.dropped scoreboard, the player could keep the item and use it to spawn mobs (griefing or for own profit.)

My command:

```
execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:villager_spawn_egg"}}]
run replaceitem entity @s weapon 
minecraft:melon_slice{CustomModelData:10000101,display:{
Name:"{\"text\":\"Blue Melon Slice\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"}}
```

My problem is that the command does not see item count, as it is often used for weapons and armor only.

One way I thought to fix this issue is by storing the amount of custom food crafted in a scoreboard item and then giving the player that same count of the custom food, but I do not know how to do this; consequently, I don't know if this works.

Is there a way to do this method, or is there another, simpler method possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summon the melon slice at the player's position in item form (with a small pickup delay) and then use **/data** to modify the **Count** property

To summon the item:

```
/execute at @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:villager_spawn_egg"}}] run summon item ~ ~ ~ {PickupDelay:10,Item:{id:"minecraft:melon_slice",Count:1,tag:{CustomModelData:10000101,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Blue Melon Slice\",\"italic\":\"false\"}"}}}}
```

to modify the Count property:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:villager_spawn_egg"}}] at @s store result entity @e[type=minecraft:item,limit=1,sort=nearest,distance=..0.2] Item.Count int 1 run scoreboard players get @s <objective_with_count_data>
```

and then clear the spawn egg from the player's inventory. There's the concept.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "elegant" way to do this. The most direct way is using 64 almost identical commands, like this:

```
/execute as @p if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b}]}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.0 dirt 1
/execute as @p if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:stone",Count:2b}]}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.0 dirt 2
/execute as @p if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:stone",Count:3b}]}] run replaceitem entity @s hotbar.0 dirt 3
…
```

Alternatively you could use [MegaCrafter10's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/361045/171580) of summoning an item entity that cannot be picked up for 1 tick and using `/execute store` to modify its `Item.Count` NBT field directly before the player picks it up, but that way the item lands in the first possible slot instead of the slot you want (and it has a delay of 1 tick).