# Minecraft replaceitem same amount

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering if there's a way to /replaceitem the same amount as a previous execute if command,

so basically I am trying to make my own blocks in a datapack that is craftable, so I've made crafting recipes that makes spawn eggs, then I want to replace them with a spawn egg that spawns an entity with a tag so I can set a block there,

but the problem is that if I just have one command like

> execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:villager_spawn_egg",Count:1b}}] run replaceitem entity @a weapon.mainhand minecraft:villager_spawn_egg{isplacer:1b} 1

that just checks if the player's active slot has a spawn egg and then replaces it with one with a tag on it, it will always replace it with 1, so if you have for example 64 spawn eggs without tag, you would still just get one with a tag,

is there any way to di this without having 64 different commands for each amount*
PS: sorry for my English it's not my primary language

Comment: This should be possible using the [`/loot` command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/loot). This was actually already asked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361043/how-to-replace-multiple-items-with-same-count-of-a-different-item/361044#361044), but the answers there aren't really good, so I'll write a new answer over there and only then close this one as duplicate.

Comment: It's actually not possible, because of the bug [MC-138299](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-138299). To make it work with `/loot`, you would need to create a loot table, which is not only a lot of effort, but also would still require you to specify all 64 variants (unless you want it to be a random amount).